# OpenGL: Can't get textures to display

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping

I'm trying to add a texture to a simple square for more than 5h now but I still don't manage to do so.

Here's the code I'm using in **paintGL()**:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

GLuint id;
glGenTextures(1, &id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

float pixels[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
};

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(1,0,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(1,1,0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(0,1,0);
glEnd();

if (glGetError() != 0)
{
    qDebug() << glGetError();
}
```

There is no errors nor OpenGL's ones. I initialized the clear color to grey.
When I try to change color with `glColor3f(...)`, it works.

I read about all tutorials that I could find with Google but no one helped.

**SOLUTION:**
I never put

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

at the right place: just after the `glTexImage2D`! Code above is edited and now work like a charm.

Comment: Before `glBegin`, try adding: `glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);` Meaning the tint will be white (texture will draw at original colour and opacity).

Comment: The square is white, only white.

Comment: Can you add the following two lines to your code after `glTexImage2D (...)` (to make your texture mipmap complete)? `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0); glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);`. After you do that, if you follow user1118321's answer, I suspect the problem will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks @AndonM.Coleman, it is the solution !

Comment: By the way, I just realized setting `GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL` to **0** is redundant (that is the default). The real issue is that OpenGL for some reason I have never understood, initially sets up textures with **1001** mipmap levels (`GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL`) and then defaults to using mipmap filtering. Your code only provides an image for mipmap level **0** so the other **1000** levels OpenGL thinks it has (**1** - **1000**) are undefined :P

Comment: **Why are you creating the texture object in the drawing function?** This is madness, because every time the window gets redrawn a new texture is created and old one is still around, never being deleted, leaking memory. Create the texture once.

Comment: You mean, in the `initializeGL()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You HAVE to specify filtering for your texture:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
```

Because default filter uses mipmaps, but you don't generate them.

Comment: You do not have to specify filtering for the texture. All textures have initial minification and magnification filters. The problem in the original question is actually that the texture's mipmap incomplete and the default minification filter is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're only using one quarter of your texture. It's only 4 pixels, and you've set the texture coordinates to be just the first pixel. If that pixel is white and your texture environment is set to multiply the quad's color by the texture, and you're set to use nearest neighbor sampling, then you'll get just the color. Try changing the texture coordinates to be (0,0) to (1,1) instead of (0,0) to (0.5,0.5) and see if that gives you the expected result. You can also try setting the various texture parameters and environments differently to see how that affects your drawing.

Comment: It doesn't work. Thanks for trying to help. (I'm still trying some parameters)

Comment: **+1**: This sounds good in theory, but I think the answer's incomplete. I suspect the OP has all default texture filter states. The more pressing issue is that the texture is not mipmap complete and the default minification filter is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`. Once the texture becomes mipmap complete, the rest of the stuff discussed in your question is very relevant.

Comment: Ah, yeah, haven't hit that one in a while, so forgot about that case. Thanks!